# eigenfunctions of the tensor Laplace-Beltrami

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\Delta_g$ be the corresponding Laplace Beltrami operator. The Laplace Beltrami operator can be applied to tensor fields. Do we also get some results about eigentensor-fields being an orthogonal basis of tensor fields?

Comment: Some time ago I ran across [this paper](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.527513) which deals with the case of the sphere. (I found it mostly indecipherable, though)

Comment: A bit late but thank you Giuseppe.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you could understand something of that paper. I still cannot. :)